# Proteus Library is empty

Tags: power-electronics, simulation, proteus

My proteus library is empty even though the folder is available, I have tried all the fixes on youtube (which are all the same).
when I click parts, the whole library is empty, I use proteus 8.10 sp3

Comment: Can you think of any reason why the installation is non-std? From a permissions viewpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t use it but try this;

explorer > properties > make hidden files and folders visible

Check if your library is here> Run> (Incl quotes).
“C:\ProgramData\Labcenter Electronics\Proteus 8 Professional\LIBRARY”